# basis and orthogonal in Hilbert

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

how resolve it. Let $h:l^{2}\rightarrow \Re $ with $h(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty }\frac{x_{i}}{i}$. Find a basis for $(ker(h))^{\perp}$, the set orthogonal of $(ker(h))$. Can I use closedness?

Answer (score 0):

Let $K$ be the one-dimensional linear space spanned by $(1,1/2,1/3,\cdots)$. Then $\mbox{ker}(h)=K^{\perp}$. So $\mbox{ker}(h)^{\perp}=K^{\perp\perp}=K$ because $K$ is closed.

Comment: And  why $(k)^{\perp}=ker(h)$?

Comment: @mathd : Because $h(x) = \langle x, (1,1/2,1/3,\cdots)\rangle$, then, by definition, $\ker(h) = \{ x : x \perp (1,1/2,1/3,\cdots) \}$, which is also seen to be $K^\perp$.